# How to pass\ in URL in windows authentication?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

To handle windows authentication, one way to handle such scenario is by passing credentials in URL itself as shown below :

```
driver.get('http://domain\username:password@abc.com')
```

my user name contains a domain ex. domain\Username. However, when i pass [https://domain\username:password@example.com](https://domain%5Cusername:password@example.com) URL it gets converted to '/'.  I am using C# selenium bindings. Please suggest a solution to get this working.

Comment: try with // not single /

Comment: Your problem is that you want to pass illegal characters in a URL which you hope to be preserved interpreted as special characters at some later point. It isn't clear what is "converting" or normalizing these illegal characters, but we'd need to see the code and know more about the total implementation layers. This isn't really about coding, so your best bet is to research if escaping or another API might be better suited. For example, this is probably already answered elsewhere: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/2277 (Or, at least it is a good place to start your research.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace any special character using its ASCII value .

> For \ , it's 092

Also, I believe browsers have dropped support for this syntax of passing credentials along with url and i am sure it won't work if you are using latest browser version of chrome/firefox.

You should  instead allow browser to show credential alert and handle it using selenium.

```
 IAlert alert = webDriver.SwitchTo().Alert();          
 alert.SetAuthenticationCredentials(userId,password);
 alert.Accept();  //not sure if this line is required.
```